# Objective-c parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, unirest

I'm totally new in Objective-c programming.

I try to make a get request from my app. I'm using Unirest for Objective-C as the HTTP Libraries.

My API will return JSON as below :-

```
{
  "merchant_list": [
    {
      "_id": "543ce2887ca4e102af44a5a8", 
      "address": "MyAddress bla bla bla", 
      "admin": [
        "543ce2887ca4e102af44a5a7"
      ], 
      "card": null, 
      "circle": null, 
      "dollar_ratio": null, 
      "fb": null, 
      "logo": null, 
      "min_spending_VIP": null, 
      "modification_timestamp_utc": 1413276296.0, 
      "name": "Lorem ipsum", 
      "outlets": [], 
      "promotions": [], 
      "referral_ratio": null
    }
  ], 
  "status": "ok"
}
```

Unirest library can parse this JSON to NSDictionary or NSArray as you see body.JSONObject[@"status"] will give me "ok" value.

But the problem is, I'm unable to access all attributes in merchant_list.

```
UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
if ([body.JSONObject[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", body.JSONObject[@"merchant_list"]);
}
```

NSLog value of merchant_list as below :-

```
2014-10-17 18:07:10.623 MyApp[18567:287513] (
        {
        "_id" = 543ce2887ca4e102af44a5a8;
        address = "MyAddress bla bla bla";
        admin =         (
            543ce2887ca4e102af44a5a7
        );
        card = "<null>";
        circle = "<null>";
        "dollar_ratio" = "<null>";
        fb = "<null>";
        logo = "<null>";
        "min_spending_VIP" = "<null>";
        "modification_timestamp_utc" = 1413276296;
        name = "Lorem ipsum";
        outlets =         (
        );
        promotions =         (
        );
        "referral_ratio" = "<null>";
    }
)
```

Any help? I already spent hours for this error.

Comment: Use this lib: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Which properties can't you access? Your log looks as though it matches the input JSON.

Comment: @Keab42 _id or address of merchant_list

Comment: merchant_list is an array.Get dictnory from this array ) at index.

Comment: It looks as though merchant_list is an array of objects rather than a single object. So you'll need to access merchant_list[0].property. I'm afraid I don't know the exact syntax for that in unirest. @Rajpal beat me to it.

Comment: @RajpalThakur thanks! sigh simple. this is why we need to rest when we have a fever

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [arrayForobjects objectAtIndex:0];
        
                                                                  NSString *strAddress=    [dict valueForKey:@"address"]

Comment: the merchant_list node is a dictionary so you should access like a NSDictionary object.

Comment: Peel it a layer at at a time, like an onion.  Assign each layer to a temp so you can examine with the debugger or NSLog it.  Note that `{}` surrounds a dictionary and `()` surrounds an array in an NSLog dump.  (Don't make the mistake of overlooking the outermost surrounding symbols.)  Take it a step at a time and there's no mystery to it at all.

Comment: noted @HotLicks well said. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I having a bad fever today but im still working. as result I cant even resolve this simple mistake.

Thanks to Rajpal Thakur for highlighting the issue.

now I can access the attributes :-

```
if ([body.JSONObject[@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ok"])
    {
        for (id merchant in body.JSONObject[@"merchant_list"])
        {
            for (id key in merchant){
                NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [merchant objectForKey:key]);
            }
        }
    }
```